# Function of a prepositional phrase

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

> 1. One of the things that fascinates us most **about cats** is the popular belief that they have nine lives.
>    ( From New Concept English, book two)

I want to know if "about cats" works in the relative clause "that fascinates us most about cat" or it is a independent expression modifying "things",  and therefore, I can alternatively say

> 2. One of the things **about cats** that fascinates us most is the popular belief that they have nine lives.

Comment: Hi. Both of these are fine. Why do think your example might be wrong?

Comment: But "about cat" would be wrong. A plural is used here. The non-count usage "about cat" would only be used in exceptional cases such as when referring to cat meat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.One of the things that fascinates us most **about cats** is the popular belief that they have nine lives.
>
> 2.One of the things **about cats** that fascinates us most is the popular belief that they have nine lives.

The phrase **about cats** is an independent expression. Therefore,the second sentence is correct. Both sentences have exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct.

The first one should, I believe, have the verb in plural ("fascinate"), as you would be saying: There are many things that fascinate us about cats. From, say, the top-five of them (the ones that most fascinate us), I want to mention this: the popular belief... etc.
The case of verbs in plural after "One of the things that..." has already been discussed here:
[Is the use of "one of the" correct in the following context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15995/is-the-use-of-one-of-the-correct-in-the-following-context)